# Opening a local folder using a link in PDF from iText

Tags: hyperlink, directory, itext

I am trying to provide a link in a PDF, which when clicked will open the folder the PDF is present. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

this one would be alot easier if u have adobe profesional...what you do is this:

microsoft word(which has ur hyperlink) >adobe pdf>change conversion settings>check the box of "add links to adobe pdf". Now same thing again:

microsoft word>adobe pdf>convert pdf.

it converts with hyperlinks...wooooilaaa...plus u got some more options to create your chart in word than in adobe...hope this one helped as welll...!!!